# Conversation-like view in ListBox or ListView

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I am trying to get a conversation-like style going with either a ListBox or Listview but so far unsuccessfully. I don't even know where to start in order to achieve this.

I know how to style ListBox and ListView in other ways, but this particular style I have no idea where to start.

Can anyone please help point me in the right direction? Below is the kind of style I am trying to achieve:

[image]

Notice how in the image above, list items are left-aligned, but every *other* list item is right aligned (but the text inside the item is left-aligned), and every second list item also has a different background color.

Comment: will a list box with custom data template do?

Comment: Yeah, I'll accept that!

Comment: Should it always be alternating or is it dependent on some property of your items? if the first, you should be able to use [Alternation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.alternationcount.aspx)

Comment: @Default, Well, if for example, the gray box sends more than one message (gray being runtime-generated messages), then there could be any number of grays right after each other - the same rule applies to the blue boxes.

Answer (score 5):

I would consider using a [DataTemplateSelector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521.aspx).  Create a different template for each of the styles.  The template selector could select one style if it's user A and another for user B or something along those lines.